# Как создать многомерный массив на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Мне необходимо создать один массив с данными из локального хранилища. 
Прикладываю свой код с комментариями, чтобы хотя бы было понятно что я хочу сделать. Сейчас я не представляю как склеить все элементы воедино.

```
function StartCompare1(){
    // записываем в новый массив имена характеристик, которые лежат в локальном хранилище
    var firstTd = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('firstTD'));

    var KeyName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('keyName'))
    var str = 'dataArray';  // строка с которой будем сравнивать имена массивов, для записи их в новый массив

    //проверяем есть ли что в локальном хранилище
    if (KeyName == null) {
       alert('добавьте товаров для сравнения ');
    } else {
        // проверяем совпадение с dataArray
        if (KeyName.filter(s => s.indexOf(str) === 0) ){
           KeyName =  KeyName.filter(s => s.indexOf(str) === 0);
        }
        // создаем многомерный массив, в котором буту хранится все массивы из локального хранилища
        console.log("KeyName" + KeyName.length);
        var newArray = [];
        for (var x=0; x < KeyName.length; x++){
            console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(KeyName[x])));
            newArray= ??
        }
        console.log("newArray: " + newArray);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте объяснить словами, что Вы хотите сделать

Comment: уф.... я записываю в локальное хранилище данные, они сохраняются там с ключами вида dataArray1,dataArray2.... Теперь же я хочу запихнуть их все в один массив, чтобы каждый элемента этого массива был массивом. для дальнейшего вывода в таблице. При этом этих элементов может быть либо один, два, три или четыре... в зависимости сколько пользователь добавит

Comment: @Елена 1) `var KeyName = []; KeyName= JSON.parse ..` - не имеющая смысла конструкция, вы создаете массив и сразу перезаписываете. 2) метод filter всегда возращает массив, просто он может быть пустой, поэтому вот такой if не имеет смысла (всегда true) - `if( array.filter(..)) { ... }`

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример данных, лежащих у вас в localStorage, и образец массива который вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: вероятно тебе нужен метод [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: @Darth вы правы на счет 1 пункта, почему то сама этого не заметила. и на счет второго пункта,тоже спасибо.)) поправлю

Comment: @Grundy Благодарю!!! работает

Comment: @Елена, если решение найдено, то ответьте на него сами и пометьте ответ галочкой.